# On Linux, how do I uninstall a version of Perl which was built from source?

Tags: perl, uninstallation

I need to un-install a version of Perl which was built from source. The directory from which it was built exists. However I didn't find a make target called 'uninstall'. The Perl version I have is 5.12.2 and is installed on a Fedora distributed Linux.

Answer (score 6):

Because perl has no 'make uninstall' target, you need to remove the files manually.  The best way to do this is to get a complete list of files installed.  To do that you need to:

1. Create a temporary directory, e.g. /usr/local/src/temp/perl
2. Edit the Makefile in your original perl source directory (hopefully you didn't delete it) and add the path from step 1 above to the beginning of all install lines (e.g. bin = ..., scriptdir = ..., INSTALLPREFIXEXP = ...)
3. Run `make install`
4. Navigate to your temp directory and run: `find . -type f > filelist.txt`
5. Edit this file and make sure you actually want to delete eveything in there (you will screw up your system real bad if you mess this up)
6. Run `cat filelist.txt | xargs rm`
7. Manually delete the perl5 library directory (usually at something like /usr/local/lib64/perl5 - you can find it in the filelist.txt file)

That's it, all gone.

Next time isolate it in a separate directory and just symlink it :-)

Answer (score 2):

If the Perl is installed in its own directory - say `/opt/perl/v5.12.2` - and was built from source, then the 'ultimate sanction' works well:

```
rm -fr /opt/perl/v5.12.2
```

I almost always build my own Perl; I always build my Perl so it installs in its own, unique directory; when I finally get around to removing it, this is how I do it.

Comment: I haven't specified a unique directory. Perl is installed in its default location.

Comment: What do you regard as 'its default location'?  It certainly complicates matters - you will know better next time.  You'll have to clean out the 'lib/perl' directory, the relevant files from the bin directory, and maybe the man pages and HTML doc pages too.  Very fiddly - a good reason for always segregating Perl in future.

Answer (score 0):

A method that

1. Assumes installation in a subtree of `/usr/local`,
2. doesn't require the build directory
3. is slightly less accurate

Run the following command,

```
sudo find /usr/local -name '*perl*' -or -name 'pod2*' -or -name '*cpan*' -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you still have the source, you can remove it by using:

```
make uninstall
```

while you are in the source directory.

Btw, I sugggest to use `checkinstall` next time while installing from source.
See [this](http://www.asic-linux.com.mx/~izto/checkinstall/)

If you (as you said...) dont have a target uninstall, then you will probably will have to remove it by hand.

Comment: There is no target called 'uninstall'. Please see the output below: [raghu@localhost perl-5.12.2]$ make uninstall
make: *** No rule to make target `uninstall'.  Stop.
[raghu@localhost perl-5.12.2]$

Comment: did you type: make uninstall while you were in the source folder?

Comment: @soulSurfer2010 Thanks for the info. I will start using checkinstall going forward. For now its search and delete inside /usr/local... :(

Comment: Well, so you will probably have to figure out where it installed it (all its files) and remove it by hand.

Comment: +1 for checkinstall. Might safe myself from future oops-moments.